# How to sort by the whole number, not just the first digit

Tags: python

I am writing some code to take high score data from an external file, take the top 5, and display them. I am nearly there, but my code only takes the first digit of the high score, so scores like 12 are seen to be smaller than scores like 8. Is there a way to take the whole number into consideration when sorting?

My external .txt file looks like this:

```
('Louis', 18)
('Louis', 4)
('Louis', 2)
('Louis', 4)
('Troy', 0)
('Andre', 6)
('Louis', 1)
('Louis', 17)
('Louis', 3)
('Louis', 9)
```

and the output looks like this:

```
('Louis', 9)
('Andre', 6)
('Louis', 6)
('Louis', 4)
('Louis', 4)
```

This is my code:

```
with open('highscore.txt', 'r') as score_file:
    scores = [line.split(' ') for line in score_file]
scores.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

print('The highscores are...\n')

for i in range(0, 5):
    print(' '.join(scores[i]))
```

Comment: You are sorting the numbers as strings and that sorts lexicographically.

Comment: That's not "taking the first digit".  That's how numbers sort if you sort them as strings.  If you have numbers, then convert them to integer before scoring.  Or, use `lambda x: int(x[1])`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) code before asking a question, in order to make sure you *understand* the problem as well as possible. If you are writing code at this level in the first place, you should have the skills needed to find out that the score values are strings rather than integers; this allows for asking the actual **question**, i.e., how to get integers instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse each line of the file. This will parse the numbers as integers, not strings.

```
import ast

with open('highscore.txt', 'r') as score_file:
    scores = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in score_file]
scores.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: I'd also recommend operator.itemgetter(1) instead of the lambda.

Comment: @KennyOstrom That's a matter of style, I think the lambda is fine. It's shorter and it's quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

your data is extracted from the file as strings and you want numbers

```
#    scores = [
#        ('Louis', '18'),
#        ('Louis', '4'),
#        ('Louis', '2'),
#        ('Louis', '4'),
#        ('Troy', '0'),
#        ('Andre', '6'),
#        ('Louis', '1'),
#        ('Louis', '17'),
#        ('Louis', '3'),
#        ('Louis', '9'),
#    ]

with open('highscore.txt', 'r') as score_file:
    scores = [line.split(' ') for line in score_file]

scores.sort(key=lambda x: -int(x[1]))
```

Comment: Please also show how you read the file and convert the data into your `scores` variable.

Comment: I get a `ValueError` from the `.sort()`

Comment: check your data, what exactly does it look like in the file?

Comment: I copied what the OP posted.